# How to retrieve records containing Russian or Arabic characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode

I need to extract from the SQL Server table all the records that contain either Russian or Arabic characters in the FirstName field - wondering how I can do this smartly within 1 SQL query.
What I tried for the Arabic is:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM MyTable
WHERE FirstName like N'%[أ-ي]%'
;
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM MyTable
WHERE PATINDEX(N'%[أ-ي]%', FirstName)>0
;
```

Could anyone advise if it's a valid approach?
Please also suggest how the fields containing Russian letters can be caught.

Thanks!
Michal

Comment: If the `FirstName` column is indeed of datatype `NVARCHAR` - then yes, this looks like a valid approach - but go ahead - just try it!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's relatively easy, actually:

```
declare @a int = unicode(N'А'); -- 1040

declare @rus table (Letter nchar(3) collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AI primary key);

insert into @rus (Letter)
select top (32) N'%' + nchar(@a + row_number() over(order by (select null)) - 1) + N'%'
from master.dbo.spt_values;

--select * from @rus;

select *
from dbo.MyTable t
where exists (
    select 0 from @rus r where t.FirstName collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AI like r.Letter
);
```

The only problem with this approach is the definition of "Russian". The Cyrillic subset of characters is used in many Eastern European languages, and only one of them is actually Russian. Others, such as Bulgarian and Macedonian (just to name a few) will use the majority of the subset in question, and they will also be flagged as Russian, thus creating false positives.

Of course, if your table contains only those 2 languages, it won't be a problem, but generally you would need a separate field with language designator.